# What is the reason for this Cython compile error when declaring a cpdef enum?

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums, compiler-errors, cython

I am working on a Raspberry PI using Python 3.4.2 with Cython 0.24 and GCC 4.9.1.
I want to use a `cpdef enum` which creates a [PEP 435](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0435/) style Python Enum (available since Python 3.4). This feature was introduced in [Cython 0.21](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/CHANGES.rst#021-2014-09-10).

I am using the following source code:

```
#lib.h file
typedef enum { A, B, C, D } test;

#lib.pyx file
cdef extern from "lib.h":
    cpdef enum test:
        A, B, C, D

def t1():
    for t in test: print(t.value)
```

However, several compile errors saying several time more or less the same like:
    - `lib.c:4664:20: error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'enum test'`
    - `lib.c:2599:45: error: type of formal parameter 1 is incomplete
     __pyx_t_4 = __Pyx_PyInt_From_enum__test(C); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_4)) __PYX_ERR(1, 56, __pyx_L1_error)`

In an interactive shell I ran:

```
>>> from enum import Enum
>>> Enum
<enum 'Enum'>
```

Obviously, the module seems to be present and working.

**My Question is:** What could be the cause of these errors?

Answer (score 0):

An enum can be declared with either `ctypedef` or `cdef.`
Try defining your enum like:

```
cdef enum Test:
    A, B, C, D
```

or

```
ctypedef enum Test:
    A, B, C, D
```

Comment: Or `cpdef enum Test`as I mentioned in the introduction. 
"Enums can now be declared as cpdef to export their values to the module's Python namespace." [Cython Changelog](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/CHANGES.rst#021-2014-09-10).  
Maybe you reread my question ...

Comment: If it were me, I'd try the tried/old way, to be sure that the problem lies where I think it lies, and when I'm sure what the root-cause is, I'd fix the situation. But that's just me.

Comment: No problems the old way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have the semicolon in the wrong place in your header? Also in the header you define `test`, but then in the cython you only refer to `Test`. Depending on what it's actually supposed to be something like below should work. Tested on a Raspberry Pi running Arch Linux.

*hello.h*

```
typedef enum test { A, B, C, D } test;
```

*hello.pyx*

The line `cpdef enum Test "test":` means "use `Test` in Python and `test` in C. See [Resolving naming conflicts - C name specifications](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#resolving-naming-conflicts-c-name-specifications).

```
cdef extern from "hello.h":
    cpdef enum Test "test":
        A, B, C, D

def t1():
    for t in Test: print(t.value)
```

*setup.py*

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(name="hello", ext_modules=cythonize("hello.pyx"))
```

*Result*

```
Python 3.5.1 (default, Mar  6 2016, 12:32:57)
[GCC 5.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import hello
>>> hello.t1()
0
1
2
3
```

Comment: I was able to run your example successfully. Unfortunately, the mistakes with the enum name was simply a typo. I was wrong about the C declaration of the enum. I updated my question and maybe you can have a look again. With the example above, I am not able to reproduce the same error like mentioned before. The original error occurres in a larger project involving a header file from a real lib. Maybe the errors are related.